# Reaching docker container on local machine

Tags: python, macos, docker, flask, containers

I've poured over the docs but there's some fundamental piece that I'm still missing.

System:

- mac os 11.2.3
- docker v20.10.5

I have a dumb hello world container in python using Flask in `http_server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello world'
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /
COPY *.py /
RUN pip install Flask
ENV FLASK_APP=http_server.py
CMD flask run -h localhost -p 80
```

I build the container:

```
docker build -t au .
```

I run the container using port forwarding:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 httptest
```

I check the container:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
c857400d06ce   httptest  "/bin/sh -c 'flask r…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   127.0.0.1:8080->80/tcp   busy_feistel
```

I double check to see there's actually an open socket on the local machine:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8080         *.*                    LISTEN
```

I open the cli in the container to triple check the app is running:

```
$ docker exec -it c857400d06ce8f2dd88d8466d57c0d274320215e24f2a4610b67d0ee75f8a2ad /bin/sh
# curl 127.0.0.1:80
hello world
```

Seems like it's all buttoned up!  I try to hit the container from my local:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

What am I missing?  I feel like there is something extremely simple that I'm glossing over, but I've reached the 60-minute mark of searching SO and docker's documentation, so I am throwing in the towel.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Run the flask application on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost Or run the container in the host network_mode, I think it will fix the issue.

Comment: This worked but feels like a hack of sorts.  `0.0.0.0` will catch all IPv4 addresses inside the docker container.  Why does `localhost` not work?

Comment: I think that's because docker acts like a proxy to deliver the request to the flask application and technically the request not come from localhost, as I said before you can set the network_mode to "host" mode, in this way the request will send from localhost

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try write in your Dockerfile the next line `EXPOSE 80`

Comment: same response with `EXPOSE 80` :(